# parsing a complex logical expression in pyparsing in a binary tree fashion

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse complex logical expression like the one below;

```
x > 7 AND x < 8 OR x = 4
```

and get the parsed string as a binary tree. For the above expression the expected parsed expression should look like

```
[['x', '>', 7], 'AND', [['x', '<', 8], 'OR', ['x', '=', 4]]]
```

'OR' logical operator has higher precedence than 'AND' operator. Parenthesis can override the default precedence. To be more general, the parsed expression should look like;

```
<left_expr> <logical_operator> <right_expr>
```

Another example would be

```
input_string = x > 7 AND x < 8 AND x = 4
parsed_expr  = [[['x', '>', 7], 'AND', ['x', ',', 8]], 'AND', ['x', '=', 4]]
```

So far i came up with this simple solution which sadly cannot generate parsed expression in binary tree fashion. operatorPrecedence doesn't seem to have help me here where there is same logical operator consecutively as in previous example.

```
import pyparsing as pp
complex_expr = pp.Forward()
operator = pp.Regex(">=|<=|!=|>|<|=").setName("operator")
logical = (pp.Keyword("AND") | pp.Keyword("OR")).setName("logical")
vars = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_") | pp.Regex(r"[+-]?\d+(:?\.\d*)?(:?[eE][+-]?\d+)?")
condition = (vars + operator + vars)
clause = pp.Group(condition ^ (pp.Suppress("(") + complex_expr + pp.Suppress(")") ))

expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(clause,[
                            ("OR", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ("AND", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),])

complex_expr << expr
print complex_expr.parseString("x > 7 AND x < 8 AND x = 4")
```

Any suggestions or guidance is well appreciated.

`BNF` for the expression (without parenthesis) could be

```
<expr>       -> <expr> | <expr> <logical> <expr>
<expr>       -> <opnd> <relational> <opnd>
<opnd>       -> <variable> | <numeric>
<relational> -> <'>'> | <'='> | <'>='> | <'<='> | <'!='>
```

Comment: Your code is a bit hard to follow, could you post the grammar in BNF?

Comment: just added the BNF ... i am not sure if it's unambiguous or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*NOTE: the `operatorPrecedence` method of pyparsing is deprecated in favor of 
the method name `infixNotation`.*

Try changing:

```
expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(clause,[ 
                            ("OR", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ), 
                            ("AND", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),])
```

to:

```
expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition,[ 
                            ("OR", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ), 
                            ("AND", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),])
```

The first argument to operatorPrecedence is the primitive operand to be used with the operators - there is no need to include your complexExpr in parentheses - operatorPrecedence will do that for you. Since your operand is actually another deeper comparison, you might consider changing:

```
condition = (expr + operator + expr)
```

to:

```
condition = pp.Group(expr + operator + expr)
```

so that the output of operatorPrecedence is easier to process. With these changes, parsing `x > 7 AND x < 8 OR x = 4` gives:

```
[[['x', '>', '7'], 'AND', [['x', '<', '8'], 'OR', ['x', '=', '4']]]]
```

which recognizes OR's higher precedence and groups it first. (Are you sure you want this order of AND and OR precedence? I think the traditional ordering is the reverse, as shown in [this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).)

I think you are also asking why pyparsing and operatorPrecedence does not return the results in nested binary pairs, that is, you expect parsing "A and B and C" would return:

```
[['A', 'and', 'B'] 'and', 'C']
```

but what you get is:

```
['A', 'and', 'B', 'and', 'C']
```

That is because operatorPrecedence parses repeated operations at the same precedence level using repetition, not recursion.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571441/recursive-expressions-with-pyparsing/4589920#4589920) which is very similar to yours, and whose answer includes a parse action to convert your repetitive parse tree to the more traditional binary parse tree. You can also find [a sample boolean expression parser implemented using operatorPrecedence](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/simpleBool.py) on the pyparsing wiki page.

**EDIT**:
To clarify, this is what I recommend you reduce your parser to:

```
import pyparsing as pp

operator = pp.Regex(">=|<=|!=|>|<|=").setName("operator")
number = pp.Regex(r"[+-]?\d+(:?\.\d*)?(:?[eE][+-]?\d+)?")
identifier = pp.Word(pp.alphas, pp.alphanums + "_")
comparison_term = identifier | number 
condition = pp.Group(comparison_term + operator + comparison_term)

expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition,[
                            ("AND", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ("OR", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ])

print expr.parseString("x > 7 AND x < 8 OR x = 4")
```

If support for NOT might also be something you want to add, then this would look like:

```
expr = pp.operatorPrecedence(condition,[
                            ("NOT", 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, ),
                            ("AND", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ("OR", 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, ),
                            ])
```

At some point, you may want to expand the definition of `comparison_term` with a more complete arithmetic expression, defined with its own `operatorPrecedence` definition.  I would suggest doing it this way, rather than creating one monster `opPrec` definition, as you have already alluded to some of the performance downsides to `opPrec`. If you still get performance issues, look into `ParserElement.enablePackrat`.

Comment: Hi Paul,
Thank you for guiding me. I have another question here though. Using three level of precedence as you suggested has increased the parsing time and also the grammar validation time has also grown drastically. Do you see any possibility to improve the query performance?

Comment: ??? I'm a little confused on what the 3rd level was that I suggested. I was actually suggesting you *remove* the addition of `complex_expr` and `clause`, and just use 'expr'. I was not suggesting that you add anything to your list of operators. I did recommend that you revisit the *order* of the operators, as traditional math evaluates AND ahead of OR, not the other way around as you currently have it.

Comment: @PaulMcG hi, string='response_code!=404 AND content='failed' OR 
 code=abc' , can u help me? how to parse this query string?

Comment: You have a new type of `comparison_term`, a quoted string. I think just changing to `comparison_term = identifier | number | pp.QuotedString("'")` should work (untested).  In future, use `expr.runTests(test_string)` and parse errors should be highlighted for you.

Answer (score 7):

Let me suggest this parsing approach, coming directly from Peter Norvig's class in design of computer programs at udacity (and tweaked for your needs).

```
from functools import update_wrapper
from string import split
import re

def grammar(description, whitespace=r'\s*'):
    """Convert a description to a grammar.  Each line is a rule for a
    non-terminal symbol; it looks like this:
        Symbol =>  A1 A2 ... | B1 B2 ... | C1 C2 ...
    where the right-hand side is one or more alternatives, separated by
    the '|' sign.  Each alternative is a sequence of atoms, separated by
    spaces.  An atom is either a symbol on some left-hand side, or it is
    a regular expression that will be passed to re.match to match a token.

    Notation for *, +, or ? not allowed in a rule alternative (but ok
    within a token). Use '\' to continue long lines.  You must include spaces
    or tabs around '=>' and '|'. That's within the grammar description itself.
    The grammar that gets defined allows whitespace between tokens by default;
    specify '' as the second argument to grammar() to disallow this (or supply
    any regular expression to describe allowable whitespace between tokens)."""
    G = {' ': whitespace}
    description = description.replace('\t', ' ') # no tabs!
    for line in split(description, '\n'):
        lhs, rhs = split(line, ' => ', 1)
        alternatives = split(rhs, ' | ')
        G[lhs] = tuple(map(split, alternatives))
    return G

def decorator(d):
    def _d(fn):
        return update_wrapper(d(fn), fn)
    update_wrapper(_d, d)
    return _d

@decorator
def memo(f):
    cache = {}
    def _f(*args):
        try:
            return cache[args]
        except KeyError:
            cache[args] = result = f(*args)
            return result
        except TypeError:
            # some element of args can't be a dict key
            return f(args)
    return _f

def parse(start_symbol, text, grammar):
    """Example call: parse('Exp', '3*x + b', G).
    Returns a (tree, remainder) pair. If remainder is '', it parsed the whole
    string. Failure iff remainder is None. This is a deterministic PEG parser,
    so rule order (left-to-right) matters. Do 'E => T op E | T', putting the
    longest parse first; don't do 'E => T | T op E'
    Also, no left recursion allowed: don't do 'E => E op T'"""

    tokenizer = grammar[' '] + '(%s)'

    def parse_sequence(sequence, text):
        result = []
        for atom in sequence:
            tree, text = parse_atom(atom, text)
            if text is None: return Fail
            result.append(tree)
        return result, text

    @memo
    def parse_atom(atom, text):
        if atom in grammar:  # Non-Terminal: tuple of alternatives
            for alternative in grammar[atom]:
                tree, rem = parse_sequence(alternative, text)
                if rem is not None: return [atom]+tree, rem  
            return Fail
        else:  # Terminal: match characters against start of text
            m = re.match(tokenizer % atom, text)
            return Fail if (not m) else (m.group(1), text[m.end():])

    # Body of parse:
    return parse_atom(start_symbol, text)

Fail = (None, None)

MyLang = grammar("""expression => block logicalop expression | block
block => variable operator number
variable => [a-z]+
operator => <=|>=|>|<|=
number => [-+]?[0-9]+
logicalop => AND|OR""", whitespace='\s*')

def parse_it(text):
    return parse('expression', text, MyLang)

print parse_it("x > 7 AND x < 8 AND x = 4")
```

Outputs:

```
(['expression', ['block', ['variable', 'x'], ['operator', '>'], ['number', '7']], ['logicalop', 'AND'], ['expression', ['block', ['variable', 'x'], ['operator', '<'], ['number', '8']], ['logicalop', 'AND'], ['expression', ['block', ['variable', 'x'], ['operator', '='], ['number', '4']]]]], '')
```

Comment: Thanks luke for suggesting ... but the solution suggested by Paul was the one i was looking for. THanks for taking your time :)