# How can I break a string into nested tokens?

Tags: python, regex, pyparsing

I have strings made up of Boolean terms and equations, like so

`x=1 AND (x=2 OR x=3) AND NOT (x=4 AND x=5) AND (x=5) AND y=1`

I would like to break up the `x` into groups that were separated by `AND`, while respecting parentheses as grouping operators. For example the result for the string above would be

`[['x=1'], ['x=2', 'x=3'], ['x=4'], ['x=5'], ['x=5']]`

`x=2` and `x=3` are in the same group because they are grouped by `()` and not separated by an `AND`. The last equation was ignored because it does not start with `x`.

**UPDATE**

Another example is

`x=1 AND (x=2 OR (x=3 AND x=4))`

where each equation should be separate

`[['x=1'], ['x=2', [['x=3'], ['x=4']]]`

The closest I found was this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133339/parsing-a-complex-logical-expression-in-pyparsing-in-a-binary-tree-fashion) but I don't know how to modify it to my needs.

Comment: You're right, I left a closing `)` in the example string. Your expected result is correct but I removed one level of the list because I don't need a nested structure like that, I thought it would make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably saw in that other question, parsing infix notation such as this is best done in pyparsing using the `infixNotation` helper (formerly named `operatorPrecedence`). Here are the basics for using `infixNotation` on your problem:

```
import pyparsing as pp

# define expressions for boolean operator keywords, and for an ident
# (which we take care not to parse an operator as an identifier)
AND, OR, NOT = map(pp.Keyword, "AND OR NOT".split())
any_keyword = AND | OR | NOT
ident = pp.ungroup(~any_keyword + pp.Char(pp.alphas))
ident.setName("ident")

# use pyparsing_common.number pre-defined expression for any numeric value
numeric_value = pp.pyparsing_common.number

# define an expression for 'x=1', 'y!=200', etc.
comparison_op = pp.oneOf("= != < > <= >=")
comparison = pp.Group(ident + comparison_op + numeric_value)
comparison.setName("comparison")

# define classes for the parsed results, where we can do further processing by
# node type later
class Node:
    oper = None
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.tokens = tokens[0]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}:{!r}".format(self.oper, self.tokens.asList())

class UnaryNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        super().__init__(tokens)
        del self.tokens[0]

class BinaryNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        super().__init__(tokens)
        del self.tokens[1::2]

class NotNode(UnaryNode):
    oper = "NOT"

class AndNode(BinaryNode):
    oper = "AND"

class OrNode(BinaryNode):
    oper = "OR"

# use infixNotation helper to define recursive expression parser,
# including handling of nesting in parentheses
expr = pp.infixNotation(comparison,
        [
            (NOT, 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT, NotNode),
            (AND, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, AndNode),
            (OR, 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT, OrNode),
        ])
```

Now try using this `expr` parser on a test string.

```
test = "x=1 AND (x=2 OR x=3 OR y=12) AND NOT (x=4 AND x=5) AND (x=6) AND y=7"

try:
    result = expr.parseString(test, parseAll=True)
    print(test)
    print(result)
except pp.ParseException as pe:
    print(pp.ParseException.explain(pe))
```

Gives:

```
x=1 AND (x=2 OR x=3 OR y=12) AND NOT (x=4 AND x=5) AND (x=6) AND y=7
[AND:[['x', '=', 1], OR:[['x', '=', 2], ['x', '=', 3], ['y', '=', 12]], NOT:[AND:[['x', '=', 4], ['x', '=', 5]]], ['x', '=', 6], ['y', '=', 7]]]
```

From this point, collapsing the nested AND nodes and removing non-`x` comparisons can be done using regular Python.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```py
operators = ["AND NOT", "AND"]
sepChar = ":"
yourInputString = yourInputString.replace("(","").replace(")","") # remove the parenthesis

# Replace your operators with the separator character
for op in operators:
    yourInputString = yourInputString.replace(op,sepChar)

# output of your string so far
# yourInputString
# 'x=1 : x=2 OR x=3 : x=4 : x=5 : x=5 : y=1'

# Create a list with the separator character
operationsList = youtInputString.split(sepChar) 

# operationsList
# ['x=1', 'x=2 OR x=3', 'x=4', 'x=5', 'x=5', 'y=1']

# For the second result, let's do another operation list:
operators2 = ["OR"]
output = []

# Loop to find the other operators
for op in operationsList:
    for operator in operators2:
        if operator in op:
            op = op.split(operator)
    output.append(op)

# output:
# [['x=1'], ['x=2', 'x=3'], ['x=4'], ['x=5'], ['x=5'],['y=1']]
```

In this case, I used ":" as separation character, but you can change it according to your needs. Please let me know if this helps!

**Edit**

For a parenthesis nesting approach, I came with something brilliant:

```py
import re
operators = ["AND NOT","AND","OR"]

# Substitute parenthesis
yourInputString = yourInputString.replace("(","[").replace(")","]")

# yourInputString
# "[x=1 AND [x=2 OR x=3] AND NOT [x=4 AND x=5] AND [x=5] AND y=1]"

# Replace your operators
for op in operators:
    yourInputString = yourInputString(op,",")

# yourInputString
# "[x=1 , [x=2 , x=3] , [x=4 , x=5] , [x=5] , y=1]"

# Find matches like x = 5 and substitue with 'x = 5'
compiler = re.compile(r"[xyz]{1}=\d")
matches = compiler.findall(yourInputString)

# matches
# ['x=1', 'x=2', 'x=3', 'x=4', 'x=5', 'x=5', 'y=1']

# Convert the list into unique outputs
matches = list(set(matches))

# matches
# ['x=1', 'x=2', 'x=3', 'x=4', 'x=5', 'y=1']

# Replace your matches to add quotes to each element
for match in matches:
    yourInputString = yourInputString.replace(match,f"'{match}'")


# yourInputString
# "['x=1' , ['x=2' , 'x=3'] , ['x=4' , 'x=5'] , ['x=5'] , 'y=1']"

# Here is the special move, convert your text into list
myList = eval(yourInputString)

# myList
# ['x=1', ['x=2', 'x=3'], ['x=4', 'x=5'], ['x=5'], 'y=1']
```

Comment: It works almost everywhere but not when there's nesting, as in `'x=1 AND (x=2 OR (x=3 AND x=4)`. In this case the parenthesis before `x=3` is not taken into account and the result is `[['x=1'], ['x=2 OR x=3'], ['x=4']],` when it should be `[['x=1'], ['x=2'], ['x=3'], ['x=4']]`.

Comment: Then another approach is needed a dynamic prog approach. Let me change that

Comment: I really like this approach, but for the nested string `'x=1 AND (x=2 OR (x=3 AND x=4)` the result is now `('x=1', ['x=2', ['x=3', 'x=4']])`. The `['x='3, 'x=4']` list should be separated since there's an `AND` between them.

Comment: Ok, let me think that over again